# fix div on top after scroll down?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

i try to fix on the top: div with id "sticky" after scrolling, but doesnt work,ithink that the java script code is the problem.
can someone help me to do it.

```js
function sticky_relocate() {
  var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
  var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
  if (window_top > div_top) {
    $('#sticky').addClass('stick');
    $('#sticky-anchor').height($('#sticky').outerHeight());
  } else {
    $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
    $('#sticky-anchor').height(0);
  }
}
    
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
  sticky_relocate();
});
```

```css
#sticky {
  background-color: red;
  height:140px;
  z-index: 1;
}
    
#sticky.stick {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sticky-anchor"></div>
<div id="sticky">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Nos Produits</a></li>
  </ul> <!--  ul end .menu -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include [jQuery](https://jquery.com/):

```js
function sticky_relocate() {
  var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
  var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
  if (window_top > div_top) {
    $('#sticky').addClass('stick');
    $('#sticky-anchor').height($('#sticky').outerHeight());
  } else {
    $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
    $('#sticky-anchor').height(0);
  }
}

$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
  sticky_relocate();
});
```

```css
body {
height: 2000px;
background: grey;
}

#sticky {
  background-color: red;
  height: 140px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#sticky.stick {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
/* added for demo */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sticky-anchor"></div>
<div id="sticky">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Nos Produits</a></li>
  </ul>
  <!--  ul end .menu -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using JQuery and **JQuery Magnet** plugin.
https://github.com/jtannous/JQuery-Magnet

```js
$(".fix-me-to-top-after-scroll").magnet();
```

```html
<div class="fix-me-to-top-after-scroll">CONTENT HERE</div>
```